# Find files in directory which starts from date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to zip the files based on today's date. I have achieved the how to zip all the files in a folder using loop but I only want to zip those files which have this format:

`yyyymmdd_filename`

Currently, my script gets today's date and convert it to desired format:

```
import os
import zipfile
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%y%m%d')
print(today)
today = str(today)
print(today)

fantasy_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\Users\\nex26da\\Downloads\\practice\\ziprep\\archive.zip', 'w')

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\nex26da\\Downloads\\practice\\ziprep'):

    for file in files:
        if not file.endswith('.zip'):
            fantasy_zip.write(os.path.join(folder, file),
                              os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file), 'C:\\Users\\nex26da\\Downloads\\practice\\ziprep'),
                              compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

fantasy_zip.close()
```

The part I am struggling with is out to identify files. Do I need to use regex or this can be achieved via some strip operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.startswith`.

**Ex:**

```
import os
import zipfile
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d') #Update!
print(today)
today = str(today)
print(today)

fantasy_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\Users\\nex26da\\Downloads\\practice\\ziprep\\archive.zip', 'w')

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\nex26da\\Downloads\\practice\\ziprep'):

    for file in files:
        if file.startswith(today) and not file.endswith('.zip'):
            fantasy_zip.write(os.path.join(folder, file),
                              os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file), 'C:\\Users\\nex26da\\Downloads\\practice\\ziprep'),
                              compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

fantasy_zip.close()
```